# TableSorter not working if checkbox precedes the text

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using table sorter 2.0. Sorter works perfectly but when i add a checkbox in a column before text, the sorter doesn't work. I can put the checkbox in the separate column. But how to make it work with checkbox?

HTML

```
<table id="tableSorter" class="table table-bordered tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tblHeadings">
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                                    
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="normalLabel">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="cats" name="categories" value="Cat1" />
                    Category 1</label>
            </td>
        </tr>                                   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
$("#tableSorter")
    .tablesorter({ widthFixed: true })
    .tablesorterPager({ container: jq("#pager") });
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it took me a while to figure this out. But I've managed to do it reading the manual of tablesorter.

You have to do a trigger update after you append the new tr.

```
$("#tableSorter").trigger('update');
```

That's basicly it.

***P.S.*** Do not copy and paste the jQuery completely, as this first bit is the full tablesorter code. Could not include it in JSFIDDLE because of http connection.

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/16sf0zby/2/)

Comment: I am not adding the rows through Jquery, Rows gets added only once at the time of loading the page. So where should i use the `update`?

Comment: @Anup, I'm trying to help you, so please help me too. What is the code you have so far? Please update your question with all the relevant code that you have so far, and I'll help you.

Comment: Thanks for Help..I got the solution...Actually previously i added a  `custom parser for checkbox`(you can check in my fiddle) & that is the reason why the sorting was not working...Also `trigger update` was not required...Just removing the custom parser did the thing..!